# Save changes in editable textbox in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've this gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
   EmptyDataText="No elements" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" PageSize="5"
   CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive datatable">                                        
         <Columns> 
             <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chkElement" runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>                                                
             </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="30" >  
               <ItemStyle Width="30px" />
             </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Performance">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPerformance" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"                     OnTextChanged="txtPerformance_TextChanged" Text= '<%# Bind("Performance") %>' CssClass="form-control input-width-medium" />
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
     <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="titletable" />
     <HeaderStyle CssClass="titletable" />
     <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="15" />
     <RowStyle CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive datatable"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

This gridview have for each row the textbox binding data from a datatable result of sql query, so the user can edit the textbox in any row of the page of the gridview.

My question is how can capture the row in the user edit the textbox, so the gridview have very page and when return to page where they have been edited a row this change not saved

Answer (score 0):

the gridview item template is not set up for tracking changes like this.
you would need to add an event to the text box and some hidden controls to allow you to get the information you need to manually make the change.

[this project](https://aspnetrealworldcontr.codeplex.com/) should provide you the information you need and already has some custom controls that should work out of the box for you.

the author has [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2005/11/09/real-world-gridview-bulk-editing.aspx) that will give a more detailed explanation to why this is happening and what you can do to fix it if you want to solve this yourself instead of using the controls they provide

Answer (score 0):

just some code snippets to get you started (search terms you can lookup).

not a question easily answered. def not worth anything less than 50,000 rep or 5000$ :D

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="order_detailsID"
     OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" OnPreRender="ListView1_PreRender"
     OnItemCommand="ListView1_OnItemCommand" OnItemUpdating="ListView1_ItemUpdating">
    <itemtemplate>
        <ul class="products">
            <li><%#Container.DataItem("name")%></li>
            <li id="price" runat="server" class="amount"><%#Container.DataItem("price")%></li>
            <li class="quantity"><asp:TextBox ID="quantity" runat="server" text='<%#Bind("quantity")%>' /></li>
        </ul>
    </itemtemplate>

Protected Sub ListView1_OnItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal E As ListViewCommandEventArgs)
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs)
Protected Sub ListView1_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewUpdateEventArgs)

Protected Sub updateOrderDetails(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = config.connectString
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "IF (@quantity > 0) " _
    + "UPDATE order_details SET quantity = @quantity WHERE order_detailsID = @order_detailsID " _
    + "ELSE DELETE FROM order_details WHERE order_detailsID = @order_detailsID"
    Dim dataItem As ListViewDataItem
    For Each dataItem In ListView1.Items
        ListView1.UpdateItem(dataItem.DataItemIndex, True)
    Next

End Sub
```